# How would you bind a drop-down to a data-source which is type of Dictionary<char, string>?

Tags: asp.net, .net, data-binding

Without creating an extra class, I  want to bind a asp.net DropDown control to a collection of `Dictionary<char,string>`. Is it possible?
Can you advise, please? Following is the code which i've tried.

```
 public void FillStatusOptions(Dictionary<char, string> avalibaleStausDictionary)
 {
      ddlStatus.DataSource = avalibaleStausDictionary;

      //TODO: Point to current avalibaleStausDictionary.Key ?
      ddlStatus.DataValueField = ... ?

      //TODO: HPoint to current avalibaleStausDictionary.Value ?
     ddlStatus.DataTextField = ... ?
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ddlStatus.DataTextField = "Value";
ddlStatus.DataValueField = "Key";
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
ddlStatus.DataValueField = "Key";
ddlStatus.DataTextField = "Value";
```

Answer (score 1):

I always do this in ASPX rather than code behind:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStatus" runat="server" 
                  Value="Key" Text="Value" .. />
```